# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib

Tags: swift, dyld

I get this error after adding a Swift class to an old Xcode project.

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`

How can I make the project run again?

Comment: You also might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364320  which shows how to debug this using `otool`

Comment: 2017 - incredibly, just **restarting Xcode** solved this heinous issue for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib/69939458#69939458

Answer (score 163, accepted):

For me none of the previous solutions worked. We discovered that there is a flag `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` (in earlier versions: "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code") in the Build Settings that needs to be set to YES. It was NO by default!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well, i switched the setting for the extension to true. The project is objc but the ext is swift and didn't worked right from the begining

Comment: This was my resolution as well. I have an existing iOS app project (ObjC) to which I'm adding a Today Extension (new target in the project, extension is a plugin for the main app). I had to go into the app target settings and enable that Build Setting and viola... problem went away. Makes sense, but given how much other stuff Xcode 6.0 automagically configures for you, it's a shame this essential option was overlooked.

Comment: This fixed my issue - we had an older project with lots of ObjC, that we recently started adding Swift to.  Even though the IPA was built and included the Swift libraries, it did not work on some iOS7 devices until this build setting was checked and we did a new IPA.  This worked across all of our troubled devices.

Comment: This worked for me. My framework was a swift one and i needed to change this setting in my swift framework.

Comment: Nothing worked besides this. You are a freakin wizard my good sir!

Comment: This should be the correct answer, simple, precise, effective

Comment: Thank you. This is the only thing that worked for me. I tried everything out there: "@executable_path", revoking certs, etc'.

Comment: This did not work for me..I believe it only works when an ObjC project has an embedded Swift framework.

Comment: This did not work for me when adding a pure Swift framework to a pure Swift project.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was facing dyld: Library not loaded: Alamofire. 
I was trying to integrate Alamofire.framework using Carthage into an older project written in Objective C.

Comment: Two years later and this solution saved my watch project :) Thank you!

Comment: Embedded Content Contains Swift Code deprecated use ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES

Comment: I tried all the solution available on stack overflow, but nothing helps can anyone helps

Answer (score 94):

This error can occur if something went wrong during the conversion of an Objective-C project to start using Swift. The issue is that the Linker build settings never got configured properly, so you'll have to do it by hand. Look for the Runpath Search Paths build setting and set it to:

```
$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I should also add that there has been recent spate of these errors caused by something else entirely - Apple made a change in Swift itself, starting in perhaps Xcode 6.1 or 6.1.1. The only solution seems to be to quit Xcode, destroy your certificates in Keychain Access, go to the Member Center and delete all certificates and profiles (except the profiles for apps in the Store - you can't delete them), and then start the entire certificate request process from scratch.

Comment: Worked for me.  Upgraded to latest Xcode version, and found that this setting path in my project was leading to the older version.

Comment: worked!! you saved my day! I was using swift GitHub control in objective C with xcode 6 GM. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Restarting Xcode did not.

Comment: worked for me. Btw, I got "Reason: image not found" at the end of the error message.

Comment: Thanks God! There it was!

Comment: Worked for me. Existing value was `@executable_path/../Frameworks` for some reason. Added `@executable_path/Frameworks` and bingo.

Comment: Also worked for me, leaving here the error "errno=2, not in dyld cache" for improving the ranking on google on this answer xDD

Comment: Worked for me using iOS 13.4 and updating an old project in Xcode 14.3.1 with mostly objC

Answer (score 79):

I'm not really sure why this question is being downvoted, I had this problem as well when I first tried to use Swift with an existing project.  An Xcode restart also fixed this for me.

Comment: I'm trying to use swift in a new iOS project and I get that error when trying to run on an iOS 8 device, but not in the simulator. Restarting Xcode, my laptop or my phone does not fix the issue. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me under Beta 4, attempting to launch a Mac app that uses a Swift-based framework.

Comment: Please include the @Developer link in your answer because it really helps.

Comment: Try this but throw in a clean as well.

Answer (score 57):

I searched long on this issue. There are several reasons causes this issue.

If you are facing when you and Swift code/library in an Objectice C project you should try Solution 1-2-3

If you are facing this issue with a new a Swift project Solution 4 will fit you best.

#### Solution 1:

Restart Xcode, then computer and iPhone

#### Solution 2:

Go to project build settings and set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` (previously `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code`) flag to `YES`

#### Solution 3:

Go to project build settings and add `@executable_path/Frameworks` to `Runpath Search Paths` option

#### Solution 4:

If none of above works, this should. Apple seems to be ninja patched certificates as mentioned in [AirSign's post](https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/)

At InHouse certificates

`Subject: UID=269J2W3P2L, CN=iPhone Distribution: Company Name, O=Company Name, C=FR`

they added a new field named **OU**

`Subject: UID=269J2W3P2L, CN=iPhone Distribution: Company Name, OU=269J2W3P2L, O=Company Name, C=FR`

so you should just recreate **certificate and provision**

Comment: Ad 2: It's now called "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES" (see comment below accepted answer).

Comment: I wanted to add... macOS projects require `@executable_path/../Frameworks` where iOS projects require it without the `..` in the middle. Changing this value is important if you've converted a target from one OS to the other.

Comment: For me, it wouldn't work without "Solution 3". I was getting the crash running on 10.3.X but not on 10.5.X (both compiled with Xcode 12-beta). The reason was now the Swift libraries are included in the OS so they don't need to be embedded with the binary. But to run on earlier OSs, you need to embed the Swift libs ("Solution 2") and _also_ have the @rpath set to @executable_path/../Frameworks for macOS. When examining the package contents of my app, I saw the libswiftcore libraries were there (ie. embedded), but the app didn't know where to find them at runtime without the rpath set.

Comment: @accfews I tried all 3 solutions but facing issue stll

Answer (score 42):

In my case I was trying to import a custom framework and was getting the similar error.
Turns out I had to import the framework in the Embedded Binaries rather than in to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Embedded Binaries are under Projects Settings ->  -> General

Comment: I was seeing this error, when trying to use a compiled framework written in swift (instead of embedding the source files as separate target). Above solution worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me after trying to link a framework partially written in swift into an old project which was entirely objective-c.  The setting was actually under build settings though.  More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163870/what-does-the-embedded-content-contains-swift-code-build-setting-in-xcode-6-do

Comment: This is under Target settings, not project, just to be sure.

Comment: I'm getting this problem with RestKit when running UITest on a project based on Cocoa pods. Does this mean I should remove the RestKit pod and add directly the .framework? (here my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997979/ios-app-failing-when-running-ui-test-in-xcode-7-1-1/34040336#34040336]

Comment: No, if your pods are working, you don't need to add it as a framework to the project. You do have to import the framework at the top of your swift code though.

Comment: That is the only answer that worked for me (twice now). Thanks !

Comment: Thanks, this resolved it for me, where the other higher-upvoted answers did not.

Answer (score 16):

For developers who have had this issue with a Adhoc/Enterprise distribution builds,

> Create the production certificate from dev portal and then regenerate the distribution profile. Download and install both of them on your Mac. Ensure you selected the right profile in your Xcode build settings and rebuild your app.

Source: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1022908#1022908

Comment: While this link may answer the question, links break.  As such, it is recommended that you include the key parts from the link.  Link-only answers are not recommended.

Comment: Worked for my enterprise app. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

**Solution 5:**

In my case, all solutions mentioned in the answer of ***accfews*** were very helpful but none has worked. I solved my problem by adding my swift library in the section "Embedded Binaries" in the "General" section of my Project's target. Perhaps is this due to the fact that I have included my swift framework in my workspace? Whatever it compiles now! Get ready Swift, I'm here!

Comment: OK, that seemed to work. I'm just trying to write a swift code library for a swift project. Somehow I still wonder if this is correct. However I'm thrilled its working.

Comment: I had included my frameworks in the "Copy Frameworks" section of the Build Phases tab - but one framework could not be selected here. The "General" allowed selection of this other framework and added it into the Build Phases, and the app builds and runs. Oddly, I could still run the app on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks Christophe. Like you, have tried all solutions, and it was clearly not intuitive to understand that a swift  library cannot be dragged to a project to another simply. You clearly need to put the library into the embedded section (aka more clearly swift module, I doubt there can be other type of embedded stuff). Even if Xcode could nicely detect it automatically and do the job for us... But that's not the task of our beloved XCode ;), definitively here to waste our time ...

Comment: Additionaly, if the library is already in the list make sure that it's marked as "Embed & Sign". This fixes my issue.

Answer (score 10):

A simple restart of Xcode solved the issue for me.

Comment: I'm gonna slap the next apple fanboy that makes fun out of resetting Windows

Answer (score 5):

For me, the issue was due to the fact that my Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority was invalid.

Download it from here:
https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Drag and drop it into Keychain Access, clean the project, and run.

Comment: This started happening after we added CloudKit entitlement. Prior to that, I guess it didn't care that the WWDR cert was invalid.

Answer (score 5):

The reasons for this occurring are many. Having just spent a fun weekend finding yet another issue that causes this (the order of code signing), I wanted to create a summary answer that brings all the possible solutions together:

1. **Add *Embedded Content Contains Swift Code* to project.**  You need to set this flag if your app contains Swift code.
2. **Clean project**.  In addition to a *Project > Clean* you can also delete the `DerivedData` and `Build` directories.  Look under the *Preferences* for the location of `DerivedData`.  `Build` should be in your project folder.
3. **Ensure *Runpath Search Paths* contains `@executable_path/Frameworks`**.
4. **Ensure that your certificate contains your Apple Team ID in the OU (Organization Unit) field**  Apple will add this for you, just revoke your existing distribution certificate and create a new one, download, install on KeyChain, regenerate all provisioning profiles, download those and rebuild.
5. **Xcode restart.**  If everything is basically good, but Xcode hasn't gotten there yet.

That's the easy stuff.  If you are doing your own command line build you may be creating your own `.ipa` files to upload.  In that case you need to ensure the following:

1. **Make sure the version of the Swift files in `SwiftSupport/iphoneos` is the same as the version in `Contents/YourApp.app/Frameworks`**  Because Swift is not yet binary compatible between version, you must ensure these versions are the one that you built your app with.  You can find these libraries under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos`.
2. **Sign the libraries and frameworks *first***.  You need to `codesign` the libraries and framework files (under `Frameworks` in the `.app` folder) first and then sign the entire `.app` tree.  The `.app` tree must be signed with an `entitlements.plist` but *not* the frameworks.

Hopefully when Swift 3.0 comes out and we no longer need to bundle Swift with our apps this whole issue will go away.

Answer (score 3):

I had an Obj-C project where I started adding swift source files.
The following fixed the issue for me:

1. Linking: `RUNPATH SEARCH PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks`
2. Swift Compiler - Code Generation: `EMBEDDED CONTENT CONTAINS SWIFT = YES`

I just created a new project from the templates Xcode 6.3 and compared the project settings with my old original project.

Answer (score 3):

Try to hold Alt, then go to Product -> Clean Build Folder...

Hope it will help someone..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12420392)

Comment: It happened after trying to add a new class in old project. There is no information how old project is. So, clearing of  project and force refreshing of cache make sense. Old project also implies there is a good chance that certificate is changed in meanwhile, because Apple Production and Developer certificates expire every year. Read about of main reason of error according to apple Technical Q&A at.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html. Same thing happened to me and Clean Build Folder makes project run again. Let people try..

Comment: It happened just after reload my iOs certificate. A simple Clean (Product menu) and everything works fine ;-)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue using an Ad Hoc (or enterprise) mobileprovision with a production certificate. Switching to a development certificate and mobileprovision solved the issue.

Comment: That might let you run the app in development, but how will you deploy if an ad-hoc or enterprise profile doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

My project is a Swift project with some Objective-C classes.
I had the same problem when signed with old inHouse (enterprise) certificate.

The following steps fixed this for me.

1. Create and use a new certificate and mobile provision.
   (Ref. [AIRSIGN’s blog](https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/))
2. Set `Runpath Search Paths` build setting to: `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks`.
   (Ref. [matt’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247890/1260976))

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 6:**

In our case, the Enterprise Distribution Certificate had been revoked. Generating a new certificate and updating the provisioning profile fixed the issue.

(There seems to be many different causes for this error. Hope this helps someone.)

Comment: This solved my issue. Holy crap what a waste of time trying to fix this. I hope this solves other users problems. I was able to debug my app with my custom framework but couldn't run the build machine's version on jenkins. Revoking my distribution certificates and generating a new enterprise provisioning profile fixed the builds for me.

Comment: This is same with Solution 4

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers given above, nothing worked.

Finally worked after updating to Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue, setting the right code sign identity solved the problem(Build settings->Code Signing Identity).

As per [Apple technical question](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html) "All Enterprise and standard iOS developer certificates that are created after iOS 8 was released have the new Team ID field in the proper place to allow Swift language apps to run"

Answer (score 2):

If you add the three frameworks via Embedded Binaries, they will be added to Linked Frameworks and Libraries also. Delete the three entries in **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** will solve the problem.

> Magic methods such as relaunch Xcode and restart the Mac doesn't work on me.

Comment: Thanks for improving the format. It looks better.
"Linked Frameworks and Libraries" is one section, not two. I change "and" to bold. @Bartłomiej

Comment: 特来shua fen zi shu bu ding

Answer (score 2):

Adding Framework as "Embedded Binary" instead of just "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" - Fixed my issue.

I also set Embedded Content Contains Swift Code flag to YES.

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade to Latest Version of OS X (Yosemite)**

After hours of trial & error I came to the resolution of this problem.
*- If this applies to your case of course.*

I had the same problem until I upgraded my Mac OS X from Mavericks to Yosemite.
*- It fixed my problem, hope it fixes yours as well*

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions that found on web, including to Apple and new certificates. Without success.

The only way I could run xcode, after 6 months of trying, was creating a new account on my macbook.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error will disappear if you add this library to the "Copy Files" segment in your Build Phases.

Comment: This worked for me on XCode 7.2.1. I used the + in the Build Phases panel, selected New Copy Files Phase, then dragged the framework from the workspace tree into the Copy Files section.  Finally I selected Destination: Frameworks.  After a clean build, my application started as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My environment: Cocos2d 2.0, Box2d, Objective C

In addition to doing the other answers above I finally went to the General tab and made WatchKit Optional.

[image: Targets:General:Linked Frameworks and Libraries: WatchKit.framework: Optional]

Answer (score 1):

And if all of the above doesn't help you and you really get frustrated... Try the best trick of all: `Clean` and just to be sure also `Clean Build Folder`. :) Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions seemed to be consistently working for me; after every couple of successful runs, it would fail again. The "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" flag was always set to YES for me.

Turns out I'd set Xcode to be 6.3-compatible. Changing it back to be 3.2-compatible solved it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried everything else. I changed it back to 3.2, cleaned the project, restarted Xcode an it worked

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well, only it wasn't locating `libswiftXCTest.dylib`.

The solution was to add `XCTest.framework` to the Tests target, in `Build Phases/Link Binary with Library`. I was getting this error even when I was trying to build the main target.

Answer (score 0):

This showed up when I added a new Today extension target with Swift language to an old project. 
**Fixed easily by updating the project to recommended settings.** Xcode 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue using Mavericks, Xcode 6.1.1, testing on an iPhone5 with iOS 8.1.1. I tried all possible solution including new certificates and provisioning profiles, but nothing helped. I did the changes to `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` and `Runpath Search Paths` both on Project level and Target level.

I have now installed Yosemite, and without any further changes, it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, for me it was Crashlytics/Fabric/Beta/Twitter/Whatever-they-call-themselves uploading a binary that was missing the embedded frameworks. If I made an archive and then exported an Enterprise build in the standard way, they worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

After months and months trying everything here... Definition of insanity... starting Xcode under a new Mac user solved it for me.

I removed ~/Library/Developer/* and reinstalled Xcode- so no clue what else to format to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Recently started getting this error again. While the top 2 answers solved it for me in the past, none of the suggested answers worked this time. I noticed the error said:

```
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8D8E5347-940A-4724-ACFE-33DF4C4DCB37/your.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8D8E5347-940A-4724-ACFE-33DF4C4DCB37/your.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
```

So I tried deleting the app from device, and I was able to build and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I added [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView) pod in my project and later removed it. I did not remove `import SCLAlertView` from my viewcontroller. Ideally it should give a compile time error, but it gave a run time error mentioning `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SCLAlertView.framework`. I removed `import SCLAlertView` from my viewcontroller, build it and it did not give the error. So in my case I was trying to `import` a library whose framework was not found. Removing such references will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. My solution is to move every `pod` declaration inside the `target` clause.

From:

```
pod 'SomePod1'
pod 'SomePod2'
pod 'SomePod3'
target 'MyAwesomeApp', :exclusive => true do

end
```

To:

```
target 'MyAwesomeApp', :exclusive => true do
    pod 'SomePod1'
    pod 'SomePod2'
    pod 'SomePod3'
end
```

My guess is that if the pod declarations are put outside the target declaration, CocoaPods(0.39.0) might use the wrong xcconfig.

Pods.debug.xcconfig (X

Pods-MyAwesomeApp.debug.xcconfig (O

Answer (score 0):

With reference to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21292

**This solution worked for me  :**

> It occurred on my side when building an app in the command line via
>   xcodebuild and xcrun PackageApplication, signing the app with an
>   enterprise profile. On our CI build servers, the certificate was set
>   to "Always Trust" in the keychain (select certificate -> Get Info ->
>   Trust -> "Use System Default" can be changed to "Always Trust"). I had
>   to set it back to "Use System Default" in order to make this work.
>   Initially we set this to "Always Trust" to work-around the keychain
>   dialogs that appear after software updates and certificate updates.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just use  "Cmd+Shift+K" and then "Cmd+B" run its work

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem after updating to Xcode 10.2 (Swift 5).  Found the following Apple link that shows two options:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1998?locale=en_US

For me, I updated the MacOS to 10.14.4 (which has Swift library included in OS).  Otherwise, "Download Swift 5 Runtime Support for Command Line Tools" for older OS.