# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib when running on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

**Update 2:** This is an old question involving the developer beta of iOS 8 and Xcode. The problem was that the Swift standard library wasn't included in the iPhone 4s iOS 8 beta. The issue has been resolved in the release.

**Update:** I've been getting fed up with the errors and crashes that come along with beta software, so I decided to reset my phone to iOS 7.1.1 and now the error is *gone*... I have no idea what is going on, but I'm going to assume its a bug since iOS 8 is still in beta. I will file a bug report with Apple and hope it gets resolved with the next seed.

---

As many other people before me, I am receiving the following error message when running a swift-based app on my iPhone (4S running iOS 8.0 beta 1):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
CDC7263B-9F18-4369-87CC-F36DB5163B99/TESTPROJECT.app/TESTPROJECT
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
CDC7263B-9F18-4369-87CC-F36DB5163B99/TESTPROJECT.app/Frameworks/
libswift_stdlib_core.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00206000, 
size=0x00128000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping 
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
CDC7263B-9F18-4369-87CC-F36DB5163B99/TESTPROJECT.app/Frameworks/
libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
```

<s>When running on the iOS simulator (iPhone 4S), I get the following (many times):</s>

```
SetAppThreadPriority: setpriority failed with error 45
```

- This is a new single view application project generated from the built-in templates with Xcode 6 beta, with none of my own code. (Also happens with an empty application)
- I have already tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib) (restarting Xcode)

I can't seem to find any other way of moving/accessing the required swift library.

Comment: What OS version do you have on the phone?

Comment: Sorry. I though I put that in. It's iOS 8.0 Beta 1

Comment: The `SetAppThreadPriority` is normal, it a framework bug in the beta. It was also seen in WWDC presentations.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice it in the presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your iPhone 4S is lower than iOS 6. We also did regression tests on iPhone 4S's on iOS 6 and 7 but they were all fine. Devices on iOS 5 and 5.1 had the same error as you have though.

Comment: My phone is running iOS 8.0 beta 1

Comment: This is the closest answer to the solution I found.  The issue was with the OS that was installed on my phone. Downgrading back to iOS 7 fixed the issue, which tells me that the current beta isn't working properly (big surprise...)

Answer (score 5):

For me, quitting and relaunching Xcode made this go away.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, restarting Xcode did not fix the issue. (I've also clarified that part a little more.)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and I think it maybe because the app has to be configured to dynamically load certain frameworks. In any case changing the "Runpath Search Paths" build setting to "@executable_path/Frameworks" seemed to fix the problem.

I'm guessing that Xcode sets this automatically for new projects but older projects may need to be fixed manually. In my older project it was blank.

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks. By the way it's "Runpath Search Paths", not "Runtime Search Paths".

Comment: And the "Runpath Search Paths" is in Project/Linking

Comment: I came to the same conclusion independently; see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25247890/341994

Answer (score 3):

I hit this problem in simulator. I tried some settings listed here http://ikevin.tw/?p=174.

In summary, Defines Module -> Yes, Embedded Content Contains Swift Code -> Yes, Product Module Name -> [My product name].

These changes managed to get me to launch and run.

The trick is that afterwards, I reverted the changes to see which of them actually made a difference. After reverting all of them, the app still launched. So it's completely unclear what actually caused the app to end up launching.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be fixing the problem with my device. I event downloaded and tried the sample project.

Comment: Not working for me either when trying to run on the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue using an Ad Hoc (or enterprise) mobileprovision with a production certificate. Switching to a development certificate and mobileprovision solved the issue.

Comment: This is the root cause. Swift apps need libswift_stdlib_core.dylib. On all iOS 8 Betas so far (1 through 5), the device refuses to load dylibs that are signed with a distribution identity. The only workaround I've heard of is to use a developer identity (and matching provisioning profile).

Comment: The fix is to re-generate your Production Cert, just done it now and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

99% of the time when you get an error like this when upgrading the beta, it's the cache in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode* directories. Delete these and rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on an exploratory project. When I tried to build on a device I got the error. All I had to do was set the 'Provisioning Profile' in 'Code Signing' and everything worked.
[image]