# What does the "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" build setting in Xcode 6 do?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, ios-app-extension

It's a new setting under "Build Options". What does it do? I can't seem to find any documentation about it. My guess is this: Does it have to be set to `YES` in a mixed Objective-C/Swift app to tell Xcode to link against the Swift Runtime?

Comment: Ran across this tech Q&A doc with some more discussion around this EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT build setting: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1881/_index.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It does not need to be *Yes* for linking. This setting is only for when you have a pure Objective-C target that depends on a mixed-source or pure Swift target.

Description:

> Enable this setting to indicate that content embedded in a target's product contains Swift code, so that the standard Swift libraries can be included in the product.

Also in the release note of Beta 7:

> The build step which embeds the Swift standard libraries in a bundle now only runs for 
>   application product types, and only if the application itself, independent of any embedded 
>   content, contains Swift source files. When building an application that itself does not contain 
>   Swift source files, but embeds other content like frameworks, XPC services, app extensions, 
>   etc. that do contain Swift code, you must set the build setting "Embedded Content Contains 
>   Swift Code" (EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT). That way the Swift libraries will 
>   be included in the application.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

According to [Embedding Content with Swift in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1881/_index.html)

> Swift standard libraries are copied into a bundle if and only if you are building an application and this application contains Swift source files by itself
>
> If you are building an app that does not use Swift but embeds content such as a framework that does, Xcode will not include these libraries in your app. As a result, your app will crash upon launching
>
> To workaround this issue, set the Embedded Content Contains Swift Code (EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT) build setting to YES. This build setting, which specifies whether a target's product has embedded content with Swift code, tells Xcode to embed Swift standard libraries in your app when set to YES

Comment: So if we have a swift project with some cocoapods that are in objective c... what should we be setting this value to?

Comment: I can't find  EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT in my Xcode project 12.4. Would you please help me create one?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that is required to have general interoperability between Swift and Objective-C. It's as simple as adding Swift code and editing the bridging header.

If you see any of the documentation about Extensions for iOS, the lingo mentions "embedded" quite a bit: embedded content, embedded frameworks, etc. Because Extensions are organized, built, and run quite differently from normal apps, I wouldn't be surprised that there's a build setting like this one pertaining to them.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that this might refer to Swift Code in an Extension that you include in your app bundle?

Comment: That would be my guess, yes. But, I know for sure you don't need it to do mixed Swift/Obj-C apps.