# The files aren't at the expected location iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have this error:

```
Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftsimd.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftMapKit.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftSceneKit.dylib, libswiftCoreData.dylib, libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftGLKit.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftPhotos.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location /Payload/App.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
```

What can I do?

I use the latest version of cocoapods, Xcode 8, `Enable bitcode` flag to NO (it's required for using dlib library in my project).  There are all libraries (mentioned in error) in folder `Products/Application/App.app/Frameworks`

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981628/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing-with-xcode-7-3-1

Comment: @Lalitkumar didn't help :(