# xcode gm ios 8 gm swift today extension crash in simulator and device: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash

I get this error when I run my Today extension for iOS:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/andy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/724FF0C3-6622-4D12-865A-90244C8C63C1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/30D8974B-ED1A-4F3A-8958-E9B7AA8901A9/App.app/PlugIns/Today.appex/Today
  Reason: image not found
```

I've restarted, uninstalled, installed xcode, rebooted my machine, created a fresh Today extension and I still got this error :-/

Same problem on simulator and on device..

Do you have any idea?

Comment: looks like a lib isn't found and an image isn't found...

Comment: Did u try to delete "Derived Data"?  Window->Organizer->Projects Tab->Press Delete button to recreate Proj

Comment: I just did delete "Derived Data", still same error. Maybe the lib is not found but it should be included as part of xcode. It has nothing to do with images. I tried it on xcode beta 6.1 and still same error :/ I managed to make a Hello World plugin on xcode beta 2 few months ago.. maybe I should download it again to see if it works back there..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Build settings -> "Embeded content contains Swift Code" -> YES seems to do the trick.

Thanks @dlinsin on twitter

If still not working check this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247890/2184338

mine is:
[image: runpath search paths]

edit:
if still still not:

- Check "runpath search paths"
- Check Linked Frameworks (I only have NotificationCenter.framework in
  my case)
- Product->clean
- Restart xcode
- Restart machine
- Check provisioning and signature

Comment: first time I use twitter to fix a bug. Google is a bit too slow when it's something new..

Comment: This is actually in the Xcode release notes. It's useful to read those.

Comment: I read it but it missed it :/ I lost lot of time on this one... I will learn it for next time. Anyway someone may do the same and it's better if the answer is here :)

Comment: It's called Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries now.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem, but Build settings -> "Embeded content contains Swift Code" -> YES invalid

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: I Build settings "Embeded content contains Swift Code" -> YES and "Runpath search Pats" -> $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks. but run project to iPhone5s(iOS8 GM) error (dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib ).

Comment: Run project to simulator success