# swift code crash ,log : dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios8, xcode6

I debug a simple swift app ,  it can normally running in the simulator, but on a real machine running on the crash immediately .

system version , ios 8 
xcode version , 6.0.1

crash log

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/002E2F03-EE10-433B-B95F-AE3760E777DA/sMdp.app/sMdp
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/002E2F03-EE10-433B-B95F-AE3760E777DA/sMdp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x100104000, size=0x00194000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/002E2F03-EE10-433B-B95F-AE3760E777DA/sMdp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib try reissuing your certificates.

Worked for me.

Comment: tell a lie - the same thing. Got rejected. I cannot reproduce the crash

Comment: Uh，but my development environment will crash as long as the real machine debugging, Is not related to the environment? I installed two versions of xcode, one is 5.1.1, one is 6.0.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26383255/1163992 Did u tried these

Comment: I estimate the Apple fixes this bug, with xcode6.1, no problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This issues seems to be caused by the certificate. Apple filled the Organization Unit in the certificate. So you need to request a new certificate en install that one. The field will be filled and your app will work properly.

Source (and credits to those guys):
https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/

Comment: Very important: revoking your signature is pretty much instant; it means the old certificate is immediately unusable! This lesson we learned the hard way when about 600 ipads were rendered useless since the app wouldn't reinstall/boot anymore

Comment: Worked for me only when deleting and creating in XCode, developer.apple.com's "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" tool apparently created new bad certs.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your certificates in Keychain , Right Click -> Get Info -> Trust - > find a field with name "When using this certificate"-> Select "use system default" option.