# Upgraded to Xcode 7 and got this: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

This is the message I'm getting in the Output window:

" dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/GdovinDesigns/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9F084ACD-DD2B-482D-97B6-D9051E46A94B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA605FA7-9E32-41EE-A8B0-7FA49BF6A04B/AppName.app/AppName
  Reason: image not found"

I'm not really sure what I should be doing. I google'd the error and found a few posts on the subject [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib), and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083134/swift-code-crash-log-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib) but nothing has worked. When I go to test the app, I see the load screen on the simulator for a second if that, and then it goes back to the home screen and I see the message above in the output window. I'm not sure if I deleted something by accident, but I don't see to be making any progress on any of the solutions that I have found thus far. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be stuck in the same place. I was able to find my error. Under the test build > Linking > Runpath Search paths I needed to add this: $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
$(inherited)
@executable_path/Frameworks
@loader_path/Frameworks
```

to Runpath Search Paths in your test target's Build Settings.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I already have this but I m still getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

Add your framework to Project-> General -> Embedded Binaries as shown below.[image]