# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts

Tags: ios, libraries, ios-charts

I get the error message "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts" for reason "Reason: no suitable image found."

I have tried various answers such as restarting Xcode.

I used pods for the installation of Charts, so adding the framework to embedded binaries is not applicable.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried suggestions from their issue tracker?

[You can find it here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Reason%3A%20no%20suitable%20image%20found)

Comment: Yes but they suggest adding it to 'embedded binaries' which I don't need as i used pods?

Comment: when i try adding it to embedded binaries i get a different error message "App installation failed. the application does not have a valid signature"

Comment: have you tried to regenerate certificates/provision profiles?

Comment: How would i go about doing that? delete the certificates from the keychain access?

Comment: create new ones in Developer Portal and update them via xcode.

Comment: have a look here, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083134/swift-code-crash-log-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a certificate issue. My mac's clock was reset, so the keychain certificate could not be validated.

I imported Apple's WWDR certificate https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/ and did clean build.

I hope it helps!