# Import custom framework in swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I did a swift framework and now i want to import in iOS application.
I added my framework `(Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Select my framework)` but when i try to launch my application appears this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/BiometricAccessControl.framework/BiometricAccessControl
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A047F3BF-A5F8-42F8-8323-2613B1B83837/app_test.app/app_test
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

How can i solve it?

Thanks

SOLUTION:
I solved it follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25772532/3086708