# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib for ALL Swift Apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dylib

I am completely unable to run any Swift app on device. I have Xcode 6.3.2 and Yosemite 10.10.3, but always get error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/

I have tried every solution mentioned in other posts:

- Have set "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" flag in the Build Settings  to YES
- set `@executable_path/Frameworks`
- Tried revoking certs and having Xcode create new certificates/profiles
- Tried revoking certs and manually creating new certs/profiles
- Deleted all profiles on developer.apple.com and computer and restarted/cleaned everything

This happens for every app I create that uses swift. No dynamic frameworks or anything unusual.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib

Comment: What version of the OS is on the device?

Comment: I have this problem too, mine is iOS 8.3 device.

Comment: Matt thanks for the references but I already had read those and tried everything - still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need to change `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` flag in the Build Settings that needs to be set to `YES`. It was NO by default!

Comment: Asker has mentioned in the question that this solution doesn't work.