# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I've been using the simulator to test my app. Today I decided to test it using other devices in the simulator and to my surprise it crashes on startup on some devices, on others it works perfectly

**My app builds an runs on :**

- iPad Air
- resizable iPad
- iPhone 5S
- iPhone 6
- iPhone 6plus
- resizable iPhone

**My App crashes on:**

- iPad 2
- iPad Retina
- iPhone 4S
- iPhone 5

The Error I'm Getting is :

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON

```
Referenced from: /Users/data/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2ACCFF1F-D35F-444A-B709-2A41AC9CC7D2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA7480F6-4032-4EB5-A51F-5D028088FFE1/Demo Mobile.app/Demo Mobile
Reason: no suitable image found.
(lldb)
```

Sometimes I even get more information :

```
Referenced from: /Users/data/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2ACCFF1F-D35F-444A-B709-2A41AC9CC7D2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA7480F6-4032-4EB5-A51F-5D028088FFE1/Demo Mobile.app/Demo Mobile
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/data/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2ACCFF1F-D35F-444A-B709-2A41AC9CC7D2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA7480F6-4032-4EB5-A51F-5D028088FFE1/Demo Mobile.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/data/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2ACCFF1F-D35F-444A-B709-2A41AC9CC7D2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA7480F6-4032-4EB5-A51F-5D028088FFE1/Demo Mobile.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/data/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2ACCFF1F-D35F-444A-B709-2A41AC9CC7D2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA7480F6-4032-4EB5-A51F-5D028088FFE1/Demo Mobile.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON: mach-o, but wrong architecture
(lldb)
```

I installed SwiftyJson via Cocoapods. My Podfile contains

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SQLite.swift', git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git'

target 'thinx Mobile' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
end
```

I tried :

- clean & rebuild
- solutions 1, 2, 3 from [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for almost a day I rebuild the project from scratch (new project, new podfile, new files but in each file copy-paste the source code from the original project) the app compiles now and runs perfectly on every simulator! No Errors.

But I still got a similar error (but different reason) on actual devices. I closed this question but there is a follow up question for that problem: [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836514/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-swiftyjson-framework-swiftyjson).

Answer (score 0):

The question is related to [iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta), that solved the issue and is a general answer for this kind of error I'd say

I experienced this at the moment of writing this post with `Xcode 8.0` (Swift 3.0) and `SwiftyJSON 3.1.3`