# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

This is a sequel to question : [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830002/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-swiftyjson-framework-swiftyjson)

After rebuilding the project from scratch (new project, new podfile, new files but in each file copy-paste the source code from the original project) the app compiles now and runs perfectly on every simulator! No Errors.

However running on an iPhone 4S or on a iPad 2 I get the same error BUT different reason :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EFC891F9-C22B-4503-8F11-F30769183439/Demo Mobile.app/Demo Mobile
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Demo Mobile requires version 2.0.0 or later, but SwiftyJSON provides version 1.0.0
```

(lldb)

My frameworks in my Podfile :

```
pod 'Alamofire' , '~> 1.3'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
pod 'SQLite.swift', git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing SwiftyJSON from the cocoa pods and adding the file manually to the project

Comment: Well, this is not a solution. A solution involves fixing the problem still using CocoaPod.

Comment: I did't mean to be destructive, but still this is a workaround not a solution. It's a problem in the configuration of cocoapod in the project. I am still working on it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I update the pod file yesterday. To solve the issue goto Xcode window -> projects -> "Select your project" and Delete the Derived Data.

Comment: tried, but it doesn't work. In my case I receive the message when running UI Tests on a project with RestKit imported using Cocoa Pods

Answer (score 0):

update your pod version. 
use target.
my problem is solved like this.