# Using CocoaLumberjack in Swift command line tool throws runtime error: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib

Tags: swift, command-line-interface, cocoalumberjack

I have a command line tool written in Swift.  I use Lumberjack in other, related apps, so I would like to get it working in this one.  The command line tool does not import AppKit. According to the DDTTYLogger.h file, if DD_CLI is defined, custom color defs. (CLIColor.h/m) are imported, rather than AppKit/NSColor.h, so it seems that I shouldn't be getting the error.

So far, I have tried adding –DDD_CLI to the Swift Compiler, Other Swift Flags. I also tried adding CLIColor.m to the build.  I am at a loss... Anyone have experience with this, or have some other things I can try?

I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this using the Xcode 8 beta, running on OS X 10.11.6, and though I had a vary specific problem, the way to debug this is the **same** for all cases.

The `otool` command can be used to see *exactly* where the linker was instructed to look for library files, along with their names.

For me, `otool -l {executable_path}` showed that it was looking for files in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/swift` which was introduced in 10.12 (Sierra).  Since I'm running 10.11.6, this is a showstopper. (And a known bug in Xcode 8 beta)

Looking at the `otool` output, there are two things to see:

1. `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` commands, which show the names of the libraries to include. 
   *The load command might show an absolute path to the file, or could be prefixed with `@rpath/` which is a shortcut used to find files.*
2. `LC_RPATH` which shows the search path for library names prefixed with `@rpath/`.

You can alter the `LC_RPATH` by including `-rpath {absolute_path_to_files}` in the `Other Linker Flags` field in your build settings (as a **temporary** work-around to get you compiling again).  For me that meant setting the rpath to the library files in the appropriate SDK's files, not `/System`.  Doing this is *fraught with peril* for a bunch of reasons.  So don't forget to undo it.

You can use a lighter approach if you're just having issues with build hierarchies.  Using `otool` you can see what is actually happening, so you can intelligently modify the `Runpath Search Paths` build setting to jump up a directory, or two and see how that affects the linker's output.