# Swift custom library could not be used error Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib image not found

Tags: swift, xcode

I have developed a Swift custom library which build to generate a Mylib.dylib.
When I try to use the Mylib.dylib library, I got an error for Swift Standard library: ***Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib image not found***.
How could resolve this issue.

I have already copied all the Swift core libraries to my custom library project and set build option "Always Embed Standard Libraries" = yes and "Framework Search Paths" = $(SRCROOT)/Frameworks (where Swift Libs are).

Thanks,

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib

Comment: ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES is the solution according to your link. But  this is not working for me.

Comment: Many many other suggestions are there. But that isn’t the point of the duplicate. The point is that this question has been discussed here many times, and this reasking of the same question adds nothing to the mix.

Answer (score 0):

Change flag `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` (in earlier xcode versions: `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code`) in the Build Settings from NO to YES.