# When i am running my app on real device its crashing and throwing an error "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib"

Tags: swift

When i am running any of my app on real device this crashing with this error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib

and it is easily running on simulator.

please help me finding the issue.

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib and this https://github.com/TinyCrayon/TinyCrayon-iOS-SDK/issues/9

Comment: Thanks,I have checked these links but these are not helpful for me

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002836/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswift-stdlib-core-dylib

Answer (score 0):

Check your Build Settings in your Xcode project, and more specifically the flag  `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` is set to `YES`. It will not work if it is set to `NO`. Do a clean of your build folder (Shift+CMD+K), and try building again.

In other versions of Xcode it may be also called `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` or `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`

Let me know if this helps.